# How to create a dll for one class that reference other dlls in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dll

I have this following class I am trying to make a dll from

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NRules.Fluent.Dsl;
using NRule.site.Model;
using NRule.site.Utilities;

namespace NRule.site.Rules
{
    public class AllowAtleastOneCountryRule : Rule
    {
        public override void Define()
        {
            FundProfile productProfile = null;
            string str = RuleTexts.AllowAtleastOneCountryRule;
            bool enabled = AllRules.GetDict()[str];

            When()
                .Match<FundProfile>(() => productProfile)
                .Exists<FundProfile>( p => enabled, p => RuleViolation(p));

            Then()
                .Do(_ => productProfile.DisplayError(str));
        }

        bool RuleViolation(FundProfile pp)
        {
            if (pp.CountriesListP.Count==0)
                return true;
            if (pp.CountriesListP.Any(c => c.Allowed))
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it has external reference

```
using NRules.Fluent.Dsl;
```

and some other classes that are up in the hierarchy

```
using NRule.site.Model;
using NRule.site.Utilities;
```

When I try the csc command I get this

```
csc /target:library /out:Mylib.dll AllowAtLeastOneCountryRule.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.34209
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

AllowAtleastOneCountryRule.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
        'NRules' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
        assembly reference?)
AllowAtleastOneCountryRule.cs(6,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
        'Model' does not exist in the namespace 'NRule.site' (are you missing a
        assembly reference?)
AllowAtleastOneCountryRule.cs(7,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
        'Utilities' does not exist in the namespace 'NRule.site' (are you
        missing an assembly reference?)
AllowAtleastOneCountryRule.cs(11,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
        'Rule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
        assembly reference?)
AllowAtleastOneCountryRule.cs(27,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
        'FundProfile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
        an assembly reference?)
```

How can I reference all the assemblies and compile this class into a DLL?
Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify addition assemblies in you command referenced in your code.

```
csc /target:library reference:assembly_contained_your_types.dll /out:Mylib.dll AllowAtLeastOneCountryRule.cs
```

Comment: I can add reference to this Fluent.dsl assembly because it's a dll. But, how can I refer to other Model & Utility? They are not assemblies but other classes at one folder up on the hierarchy. And Those files contain other references.

Comment: `They are not assemblies but other classes at one folder up on the hierarchy.` If they are in another `cs` file you should compile them as well. List them separated by space.

Comment: But there are other files that are referenced in those files. I mean there are maybe 50 files that are interconnected in someway. How am I supposed to compile all of them together? Can I do something like removing this file "AllowAtLeastOneCountryRule.cs" from the project  and compiling the rest of the project. Get the dll of the project from bin folder, reference it in this file and then try "csc" with reference to "FluentDsl.dll" and "myproject.dll" only. Will this look feasible to you?

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio or so?

Comment: Yes. I tried and it worked actually. I took the assembly of my entire project (from bin) and the other external assembly. Then used this command "csc /target:library out:/myLib.dll AllowAtLeastOneCountryRule.cs /r:NRule.site.dll /r:NRules.dll". However, I don't know if there is other efficient way of doing it.